# JavaScript: asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to understand the conept of asynchronous code, so I  produced the following code:

```
"use strict";
var fs = require("fs");
var buf = new Buffer(1024);

console.log("Global Start");
console.log("+++ Async open - truncate - close: open file2 called");
fs.open("file2.txt", "r+", function (err, fd) {
  console.log(" Global + 1 Start");
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  console.log(" +++ Async file2 opened successfully!");

  // Truncate the opened file.
  console.log(" +++ Async open - truncate - close: truncate file2 called");
  fs.ftruncate(fd, 10, function (err) {
    console.log("       Global + 2 Start");
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("       +++ truncate file2 successfully!");
    console.log("       +++ Async open - truncate - close: read file2 called");
    fs.read(fd, buf, 0, buf.length, 0, function (err, bytes) {
      console.log("         Global + 3 Start");
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      // Print only read bytes to avoid junk.
      if (bytes > 0) {
        console.log("           Global + 3 +++ truncate read: '" + buf.slice(0, bytes).toString() + "'");
      }

      // Close the opened file.
      console.log("         Global + 3 +++ truncate - open - close: close file2 called");
      fs.close(fd, function (err) {
        console.log("               Global + 4 Start");
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("               Global + 4 ++++++++++++++++++++ Async open - truncate - close file2 + closed ++++++++++++++++++++");
        console.log("               Global + 4 End");
      });

      console.log("         Global + 3 End");
    });
    console.log("       Global + 2 End");
  });
  console.log(" Global + 1 End");
});
console.log("Global End");
```

Which created the following output.

```
Global Start
+++ Async open - truncate - close: open file2 called
Global End
        Global + 1 Start
        +++ Async file2 opened successfully!
        +++ Async open - truncate - close: truncate file2 called
        Global + 1 End
                Global + 2 Start
                +++ truncate file2 successfully!
                +++ Async open - truncate - close: read file2 called
                Global + 2 End
                        Global + 3 Start
                        Global + 3 +++ truncate read: 'This is a '
                        Global + 3 +++ truncate - open - close: close file2 called
                        Global + 3 End
                                Global + 4 Start
                                Global + 4 ++++++++++++++++++++ Async open - truncate - close file2 + closed ++++++++++++++++++++
                                Global + 4 End
```

So here is what I make of it:

---

1. Global scope: "Global Start"
2. Call fs.open with a callback function that gets executed when fs.open is done.
3. fs.open starts working and instead of waiting for the result, the next task on global level get executed, which is "Global End".
4. Now fs.open is done and the callback function gets called. We enter Global +1 scope.
5. Global + 1 scope: "Global + 1 Start"
6. Call fs.ftruncate with a callback function that gets executed when fs.ftruncate is done
7. fs.ftruncate starts working, and while it works the remaining code on Global + 1 scope gets executed, which is "Global + 1 End".
8. When fs.ftruncate is done it's callback function gets called.

Global + 3 and Global + 4 follow the same pattern.

---

So my Questions are;

Is my description of what happens in the code correct?

It seems to me like asynchrnous code is executed from the most outer bracket (the Global scope) to the most inner bracket (the Global + 4 scope). It is not from the inner most to the outer bracket (like in mathematics) and it is not from topline to buttomline (like synchronous code).  Is that correct?

What happends if a function on Global Scope is done and executes its callback function before the other code on Global Scope is done. Will the callback wait for the Global code to finish?

Will the results of the output come in different order if the same code is executed with different files to process which take different times to process?

Comment: Your description is basically correct except I'd suggest forgetting about brackets and weather something is executed innermost or outermost. The thing you're missing in the description is **time**. Asynchronous callbacks merely executes at a later **time**. For me, the best way to think of them is as instructions you tell a video (or PVR) recorder: record at "some later time" then continue your current function (which is to show me what's on TV)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a pretty good grasp on this. As to your questions:

1. "It seems to me like asynchronous code is executed from the most outer bracket (the Global scope) to the most inner bracket"

An asynchronous call will execute like any other command, but instead of waiting for the results the next command below this will get executed. The next command is the immediate line after the async callback unless there is a function call of some sort.

2. "Will the callback wait for the Global code to finish?"

Global scope variables will not wait for async call and vice versa. The code will run and some code later that relies on variables inside the async call may or may not get the updated versions of those variables. It is dependent upon if the async call finished on time or not.

3. "Will the results of the output come in different order if the same code is executed with different files to process which take different times to process?"

Again, the order in which code is executed is dependent upon the speed of the asynchronous call. The code will always be read in the same order. To prevent beating your async call you would make sure all of your JS that relies on the async call goes inside the callback because it would then wait until the async is finished.

I believe I answered all of your questions, anyone comment if I am missing something.